# DHCP client send hostname "linux"

Tags: dhcp, dhcpcd

I start by saying that my experience in networking is somewhere between low and medium.

I'm working on a Linux machine with DHCP configured and from tcpdump traces I see that the dhclient send the hostname "linux" in Option 12, Request packages. I verified the files /etc/hostname, /etc/hosts and /etc/dhclient.conf and there's no parameter related to the hostname that have the value "linux". I must specify that I use dhcpcd.

Any help/hint is appreciated since I don't have any ideas where that value is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man 5 dhclient.conf`, the config entry is `send host-name <...>`. It's near the bottom. The example they give is:

```
interface "ep0" {
  send host-name "andare.example.com";
  request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name;
}
```

But, I doubt you need to put it under an  interface section. I would not worry if it's sending `Linux`, just override it.

It may be being set via systemd. on openSUSE, the manpage for dhclient says it has a `-H` switch. YMMV.

Comment: I checked the dhclient.conf and there's no send host-name. Only some send fqdn, but with the correct domain name. While in DHCP file from /etc/sysconfig/network there's DHCLIENT_HOSTNAME_OPTION="AUTO".

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's in dhclient.conf or not, just go by what the man page says. That `send fqdn` id for DDNS, again, look at the manpage.

Comment: Thankgs, I'll try!